# Issue with apache poi - Upgrading AEM from 6.5.2 6.5.5

Tags: java, apache-poi, aem

We are planning to upgrade our AEM from 6.5.2 to 6.5.5 through service pack: https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/experience-manager-65/release-notes/service-pack/sp-release-n....

While following the instruction, I installed the 6.5.5 package and then updated pom.xml to update uber jar to 6.5.5. I can see those changes in my project.

But when I try to compile and build the project I get below error:

[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :

[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------

[ERROR] /Users/mukmayu/All_Documents/Project_Official/Manulife_CEA/Code_Workspaces/AEMCodeAll/aem-global/core/src/main/java/ca/manulifeglobal/core/util/AssetAccessUtils.java:[99,7] cannot access org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocument

class file for org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocument not found

[ERROR] /Users/mukmayu/All_Documents/Project_Official/Manulife_CEA/Code_Workspaces/AEMCodeAll/aem-global/core/src/main/java/ca/manulifeglobal/core/util/AssetAccessUtils.java:[132,19] cannot access org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart

class file for org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart not found

[ERROR] /Users/mukmayu/All_Documents/Project_Official/Manulife_CEA/Code_Workspaces/AEMCodeAll/aem-global/core/src/main/java/ca/manulifeglobal/core/util/AssetAccessUtils.java:[158,15] cannot find symbol

symbol:   method write(java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream)

location: variable workbook of type org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook

I have added dependency for poi in my project and did maven update..and now I see apache poi 4.0.1...but issue reamains.
Any suggestion...?

Comment: Make sure you include `poi-ooxml` if you want to work with the XxxF file formats as you seem to wantto

Comment: If you go to <your-instance>/system/console/depfinder and put `org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocument` do you get a dependency as result?

Comment: Mayukh Mukherjee - I have the same issue. Could you please tell me how did you resolve this issue? open similar question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76121447/noclassdeffounderror-on-org-apache-poi-xssf-usermodel-xssfworkbooktype-in-aem-6

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try to include below dependency in your project

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
<dependency>    
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>    
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>    
    <version>5.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```