# NoClassDefFoundError on org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbookType in AEM 6.5.16

Tags: java, maven, junit, apache-poi, aem

I am upgrading the uber jar version to 6.5.15 after upgrading the version I was getting a compilation error. I followed [Issue with apache poi - Upgrading AEM from 6.5.2 6.5.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63384557/issue-with-apache-poi-upgrading-aem-from-6-5-2-6-5-5) and resolved the compilation issue. But after fixing the compilation issue I am getting junit failure with the below error message.

```
GetFolderDetails.validateFolderName:121 Unexpected exception thrown: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbookType
```

This error was not appeared before, it started coming up after uber jar versions change. When I checked the java class I found that XSSFWorkbook is having problem. I see below code

Workbook workbook = new org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook();

Any idea why idea why junit class is unable to initialize class org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbookType?

Answer (score 0):

Try including MS Office ooxml schemas in the maven dependencies: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.4

There could be a change in transitive dependencies of Apache POI, the MS office Java API.